# Is there a way to print the time every minute from a piped tail command without interrupting the output?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a long piped tail command that I execute over `ssh` (eg. `tail -f <file>|egrep -v "lol"`), and normally there is not much output and want to be sure that the connection is stile live and would like to print the time every 60 or 300 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to turn the order of the command around and get the `date` in your `tail -f` output:

```
( while : ; do date; sleep 60; done )& tail -f <file>|egrep -v "lol"; kill %1
```

Note: you are backgrounding the process that is providing the date every 60 seconds, thus you need to kill the backgrounded job when done `kill %1`. If you have backgrounded multiple processes, you will need to capture the job number. I have tried with syslog and it seemed to work. Report back if it works in you situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tail -f file | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$|=1} print unless /lol/'
```

Of course, if you're just looking to print a timestamp, try:

```
tail -f file | { while sleep 60; do date; done& grep -v lol; }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only check for a new line every 60 seconds though? Is there any way to do this without interrupting the tail?

Comment: No, the grep is running continuously, while the sleep loop is running asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Append a little script like this to the end of the pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash
while : ; do
    # Read input with timeout
    read -t 10 line
    # Output if we got anything and remember current time in "last"
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && last=$(date +%s) && echo $line
    # Check if we are due a timestamp and output if required
    now=$(date +%s)
    diff=$((now-last))
    [[ $diff -ge 60 ]] && last=$(date +%s) && date
done
```

It reads from `stdin` with a 10 second timeout. if data keeps coming it keeps printing. Each time it does some output, it updates the variable `last` with the time of the last output. Then each time around it checks whether there has been any output in the last 60 seonds, and if not, it outputs the current time.

Save the above in a file called `monitor`, and then make it executable (once only) and run like this:

```
chmod +x monitor
yourpipe ...| ... | ./monitor
```

It can be abbreviated at the expense of some clarity, like this. Also, the exec of `date` can be avoided by using the bash `SECONDS` built-in:

```
#!/bin/bash
last=$SECONDS
while : ; do
    read -t 10 line && [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && last=$SECONDS && echo $line
    [[ $(($SECONDS-last)) -ge 60 ]] && last=$SECONDS && date
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, slightly different approach... make a FIFO and send your original pipe's output there, and tail that, but in the background, have a little loop that also sends the timestamp to the FIFO once per minute. Something like this (untested)

```
mkfifo FIFO
original_pipe | ... | ... > FIFO &
```

Now inject a timestamp into the FIFO every 60 seconds as well:

```
while :; do date > FIFO; sleep 60; done &
```

Now just tail the FIFO

```
tail -F FIFO
```